# how to combine multiple properties in to one cell on SlickGrid?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I want to combine multiple properties form the data item into a cell on slick grid. I was checking through the samples but did not find anything similar. The column formatter will just have access to current property.

say for example I have a json object:

```
{FirstName: 'abc', LastName: 'def', ContactNumber: '....', Email: '....'}
```

can I combine FirstName and LastName in to a cell?

the resulting grid will look like this:

```
Name     | Contact No|  Email
abc def  | ....      | ....
```

Comment: The formatter does have access to the entire "row" object. I forget which argument it is, but in the examples it would be called `dataContext`. So you'd return `dataContext.FirstName + ' ' + dataContext.LastName`.

Comment: oh yeah.. you are right.. I just missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer for completion. @idbehold mentioned the answer in the comment.

The formatter function looks like this:

```
function nameFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext)
{
    return dataContext.FirstName + ' ' + dataContext.LastName;
}
```